# Dead lock in the mutex, condition variable code?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, deadlock, condition-variable

I'm reading the book, Modern Operation Systems by AS TANENBAUM and it gives an example explaining condition variable as below. It looks to me there is a deadlock and not sure what I miss.

Lets assume *consumer* thread starts first. Right after *the_mutex* is locked, *consumer* thread is blocked waiting for the condition variable, *condc*.

If *producer* is running at this time, *the_mutex* will still be locked, because *consumer* never releases it. So *producer* will also be blocked.

This looks to me a textbook deadlock issue. Did I miss something here? Thx

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX 10000000000         /* Numbers to produce */
pthread_mutex_t the_mutex;
pthread_cond_t condc, condp;
int buffer = 0;


void* consumer(void *ptr) {
  int i;

  for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex); /* lock mutex */

    /*thread is blocked waiting for condc */
    while (buffer == 0) pthread_cond_wait(&condc, &the_mutex);
    buffer = 0;
    pthread_cond_signal(&condp);    
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex);
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void* producer(void *ptr) {
  int i;

  for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex); /* Lock mutex */

    while (buffer != 0) pthread_cond_wait(&condp, &the_mutex);
    buffer = i;
    pthread_cond_signal(&condc);    
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex);   
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  pthread_t pro, con;

  //Simplified main function, ignores init and destroy for simplicity
  // Create the threads
  pthread_create(&con, NULL, consumer, NULL);
  pthread_create(&pro, NULL, producer, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wait on a condition variable, the associated mutex is released for the duration of the wait (that's why you pass the mutex to pthread_cond_wait).

When pthread_cond_wait returns, the mutex is always locked again.

Keeping this in mind, you can follow the logic of the example.